# How can I ignore spaces from the input file?

Tags: c++

How can I remove spaces from the input ?? It is an integer array.
the input is like this:

```
5 6 2 9
3 1 11 4
```

I will have to take it as an integer. Then sort it using bubble sort. Problem is I am getting outputs like these: `9 8 7 4 2 1 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460`

```
class inout
{
public : 
    int i[10];

    inout()
    {

    }

    void read()
    {
        ifstream inClientFile( "input.txt", ios::in );
        if ( !inClientFile )
            {
            cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
            exit( 1 );
            }
        int n=0;

        while (inClientFile >> i[n])
        {

            n++;
        }
        cout << " Data read complete" << endl;
    }

    void write()
    {
       ofstream outClientFile( "output.txt", ios::out ); 

       if ( !outClientFile ) {  
          cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
          exit( 1 );

       } 


        int n=0;
        for (int l=0 ; l < 10 ; l++)
        {
          outClientFile << i[l] << " " ;

        }   
        cout << " Data Write complete"  << endl;
    }

    void sortData(int asc )
    {
        int pos=0;
        int temp;
        temp = i[0];

        // asending 

        if (asc == 1)
        {
        for (int p = 0; p < 10 ; p ++ )
        {

        int pos=p;
        int temp2,temp = i[p];
            for (int j = p+1 ; j < 10 ; j ++ )
            {
                if (pos == p)
                {
                    if (i[p] > i[j])
                    {
                        pos = j;
                        temp = i[j];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (i[pos] > i[j])
                    {
                        pos = j;
                        temp = i[j];
                    }
                }
            }

            temp2 = i[pos];
            i[pos] = i[p];
            i[p] = temp2;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        for (int p = 0; p < 10 ; p ++ )
        {

        int pos=p;
        int temp2,temp = i[p];
            for (int j = p+1 ; j < 10 ; j ++ )
            {
                if (pos == p)
                {
                    if (i[p] < i[j])
                    {
                        pos = j;
                        temp = i[j];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (i[pos] < i[j])
                    {
                        pos = j;
                        temp = i[j];
                    }
                }
            }

            temp2 = i[pos];
            i[pos] = i[p];
            i[p] = temp2;
        }


    }
    }

};

int main()
{
    int d;


    inout x;
    x.read();
    cout<<"Press 1 to sort into ascending order"<<endl<<"Press any other key to sort into descending order"<<endl;
    cin>>d;
    x.sortData(d);  
    x.write();

}
```

Comment: You should avoid "magic numbers" like the ten in `for (int p = 0; p < 10 ; p ++ )`.

Comment: What about having a string equivalent and doing String.Replace(" ", ""); then convert to the integer using string = int.Parse(string);

Answer (score 0):

You should record how many input numbers are actually read in `inout::read()` instead of always sorting and printing the whole array. There are 8 numbers in your example input, but your code always sorts and prints 10 numbers.

Comment: Ummm How can I get the size of the array ??

Comment: @user1596763, The easiest way is to use a `std::vector<int>` to hold the file contents. Then just use `std::vector<int>::size()` to get the size. You can also initialize the vector with the file contents using the range form of the constructor and `std::istream_iterator`.

Comment: @KnightFall You can store the `n` computed in `inout::read()` as a new member variable of `class inout` so you could get correct element count in `sortData()` and `write()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't spaces. Stream extractors treat whitespace (including multiple spaces, newlines, tabs) as separators.

The input loop carefully counts the number of values that it has read, but the rest of the code ignores that count. Your input sample has 8 elements, but the code is hardcoded for 10 elements. The last two elements in the array `i` have nonsense values, and that's a recipe for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

May be read the entire file's contents into a string, using ifstream's rdbuf() method:

```
std::ifstream in("myfile");

std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << in.rdbuf();

std::string contents(buffer.str());
```

Then use the usual `string` manipulation tricks, to get the integers.
something like this:

```
istringstream iss(contents);
int x=0;
do{
x=0;
iss>>x;
}while(iss);
```